# Insert only two columns data from another table and leave the rest with default values

Tags: mysql, sql, datatable, sql-insert, sql-query-store

MySql table has four columns. How to insert two column data from another table and leave the other two columns to be filled out manually.

```sql
insert into faulthistory (D_ID,D_IP,D_Status,Date_time) 
select IP_ID,D_IP from device where D_IP='192.168.1.1', '0',now();
```

Comment: not possible. You need to use 2 insert statements

Answer (score 2):

Put the "manual" values in the select list:

```
insert into faulthistory
 (D_ID,D_IP,D_Status,Date_time) 
select IP_ID, D_IP, '0', now() from device where D_IP='192.168.1.1'
```

You could alternatively define default values for these two columns.